# how can I remove my lock screen pin?

Tags: lock-screens

I googled for the answer, but kept getting sent in options,where I cant find how. Could you please help me? I have a Galaxy S3 Neo.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings menu and under settings option you can find lock screen options try other security options or remove all it will ask you to re-enter screen pin to disable or change.